# Continuous Integration from TFS to Azure Inconsistent to Visual Studio Deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, azure, tfs, tfsbuild

We are working to migrate to Azure Cloud Services (not Web Site) for our ASP.net Web Application. We are wanting to start using the Team Foundation Service with 'Continuous Integration' publishing like we currently use between AppHarbor and GitHub.

We are running into challenges when using TFS's 'Continuous Integration' feature. The builds are inconsistent when comparing Visual Studio to Azure Cloud Service to TFS to Azure Cloud Service. When we publish to Azure Cloud Service using the TFS's 'Continuous Integration', our static pages work fine but for the pages that have an *.cs extension are not able to find the controls we have placed on those pages. However, when we publish using Visual Studio 2010 to Azure Cloud Service, these pages operate correctly.

Can you offer any insight to why Team Foundation Service's Continuous Integration to Azure Cloud Service would result in pages with an *.cs extension not being able to find the controls we have placed on those pages while a build and deployment using the same exact code from Visual Studio 2010 to Azure Cloud Service works perfect?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Could be because Team Foundation Service doesn't contain all your binaries. Does a TFS build work when you do a check-in?

Comment: Yes, TFS successfully builds to Azure Cloud Services on each check-in. We will check to make sure that TFS contains all the binaries. We will keep you posted on what we find. - Micky

Comment: @MickyThompson Were you able to find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the referred assemblies that include the custom controls are "NOT" referred from GAC. Ideally put those in a folder (call it libs or references etc to easily identify). Then refer the assemblies from that location in your project, also don't forget to mark them **Copy Local = True**.

**Anything** that is not part of the framework should be included like this.